# Extended properties in JS?

Tags: javascript

Can we associate property with object at runtime in javascript
Just like we do in C#. 
 like

```
class abc
{
a =1;
b=2;
}

abc obj;

obj.a // is right
//but can we do 
obj.c //.......... by any mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function abc(){
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
}
var obj = new abc();
var obj2 = new abc();
obj.c = "something"; // will affect only this instance
obj2.prototype.d = "something else"; // this will influence all abc instances
alert(obj.d);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now if we want to attach an array or a function with object at run time, is it posible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that in JS. That new property 'c' however will only be valid for that particular instance of teh class.